# Escape velocity for electric field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law, escape-velocity

As we know gravitational force and electric forces are quite similar I was wondering if there is minimum velocity called escape velocity required to escape gravitational field of earth so is there a minimum velocity to escape electric field of earth since electromagnetic forces are stronger than  gravitational forces. If yes then how to calculate it?

Comment: Clarify if you want it for a general electric field configuration or electric field due to any celestial body.

Comment: For a celestial body

Answer (score 1):

A problem is that the Earth is not just a conducting sphere with charge on its surface as this text [Electricity in the Atmosphere](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html) illustrates.

However you also need to consider the charge on the object trying to escape which may well be under the influence of other charges which are surrounding it.

Comment: In this way why don't we consider gravitational filed of nearby particles

Comment: You have answered your own question with the statement "electromagnetic forces are stronger than gravitational forces" implying that gravitational forces are very weak and only come into play when at least one of the masses (eg Earth) is very large.  The gravitational attraction between two atoms is minute.

Comment: Thank you for guidance